# how to pass checkboxes to mysql using ajax(jquery)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to pass values of multiple checkboxes to mysql using array via ajax(Jquery).
Any ideas?

I wrote two pices of code , maybe some one help me to combine them?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var selected = [];

$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
}).get();

 $("#ajaxDiv").html(selected);


 });
```

AND

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


    $('.item').change(function(){

            if($(this).is(':checked')){

                var name = $(this).val();
                $.post('load.php', {name:name}, function(data){
                    $('#name-data').html(data);
                });
            }
    });
});

  </script>
```

Comment: How are you planning to connect with mysql? Personally I would use PHP with a rest service, clean the variables, then add them to mysql. Just store them in mysql as BOOL eg. store the array values in their own table with a bridge if you need to.

Comment: did you turn anything in php? where is your load.php
all of the work for setting a value to sql, ould be done in PHP,  do you done with server side code ?

Comment: just wrap them in a nice <box> and add a a <bow> :) Merry XMas Checkboxes!

Answer (score 0):

2nd code: in "load.php" you can access the sent values by using $_POST['name'], etc and put them in the database with a simple mysqli-query. dont Forget to check the values, before you put them into the database.